# Format a date string using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a date that is coming from the database like so:

```
26/01/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

and I am capturing it as a string

```
questionItem.DueDate = dataReader[6].ToString();
```

I am trying to reformat this string so its looks like

```
2016-01-26
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What is the actual type of the database column with the date?

Comment: Have you already done some googling before asking this question ? and I don't understand people who upvote such answers, they should be comments not answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify format like below.

```
 questionItem.DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader[6]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) form DateTime formating.

Comment: This gives me an error: Error 1 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Try my updated statement, I added convert statement to convert it to datetime first. Basically return type should be datetime in order to use above code.

Answer (score 3):

Should look something like this

```
questionItem.DueDate = dataReader[6].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

For further readings checkout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This gives me an error: Error 1 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Could you provide the code you are having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

```
questionItem.DueDate = new DateTime(dataReader[6]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Or

```
questionItem.DueDate = dataReader[6].Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].Replace('\\', '-');
```